# Increasing the points in a time scale changes the shape of the fft-function

Tags: fourier-analysis

This question is derived by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733354/changing-the-amount-of-points-changes-the-result-of-the-fft) question and the corresponding answer. The problem was that I had a $sech(x)$-function in a specific time interval, and I applied a `fft` on it. But when I increased the amount of points in the time interval, the resulting function got narrower. The answer was that I am shifting the original function to higher frequencies (by keeping it at the same width), and therefore reducing the size of the `fft`-result.
As far as I know, that is not correct. Is there a mathematical explanation why I get a narrower `fft`-function when I am increasing the amount of points in the time interval, but keeping the FWHM of the original function constant?

Answer (score 0):

The fourier transform of your function has not gotten narrower. It is exactly as it was before. You simply have appended more empty space to the size because the frequency bandwidth is limited.

Addition: If you *expand* the time interval, the frequency domain will get denser. If sample the same time interval more densely, the frequency domain will expand.

Comment: In my example I kept the whole time interval the same, just increased the amount of points in this time interval.

Comment: That is what said. The effects are swapped in time and frequency domain: "If sample the same time interval more densely, the frequency domain will expand"

Comment: But is there a final solution? Or is it always depending on the number of sampling points?

Comment: It will always depend on the number of sampling points. To understand this, you need to under stand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem You need to sample the time signal with twice the frequency of the highest frequency component. That will suffice.